# How to dispatch the redux hook useDispatch on load (not on a button click)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have the following code (**App.tsx**):

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getAllMovies } from './redux/actions/movie';
import { Movie } from './redux/interfaces/movie';

function App() {
  const movies = useSelector((state: any) => state.movies);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(getAllMovies())}>Get all movies</button>
      {movies.items.map((movie: Movie) => <div>{movie.title}</div>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I click the button, it successfully loads the data from redux store. However, I don't want to load the data on a button click.

Could you let me know how to **load the data on page load** please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` hook for this purpose.

Try as the following instead of button `onClick` event:

```
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getAllMovies());
}, []);
```

See from [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) documentation:

> If you're familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of `useEffect` Hook as `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount` combined.

**+1 suggestion:**

The empty dependency array is needed because it runs only once the `useEffect` callback with the required data fetching action technically on load event.

I hope this helps!